Efficient chain rule implementation
(there is a fair amount of context here) I am implementing a generalized chain rule to do some work, say for order 3 in derivatives ($\partial_i = \partial/\partial x_i$):
\begin{align}
\partial_i \partial_j \partial_k f(y) = f^{(1)}(y) y_{ijk} + f^{(2)}(y)( y_i y_{jk} + y_j y_{ki} + y_k y_{ij}) + f^{(3)}(y)y_i y_j y_k 
\end{align}
where $f^{(1)}(y) = (d/dy) f$ and so on for higher derivatives and $y_i =  \partial_i y$ and so on for higher derivatives.
Suppose $f(y)=\log(y)$ and $y =  \sin(u*v*w)$ and we are taking the derivative at $(u,v,w) = (2,4,5)$. I make a vector with the values of f derivatives at this point (from $1/\sin(40)$ up to $1/\sin(40)^3$ )
vec1 = {1.34208, -1.80117, 2.41732}

and a vector of the necessary tensors of the first formula (vectemp is an intermediate variable, vec2 is relevant.)
rules = {u->2, v->4, w->5};
vectemp = {
    D[Sin[u*v*w], {{u,v,w}}]/.rules,
    D[Sin[u*v*w], {{u,v,w},2}]/.rules,
    D[Sin[u*v*w], {{u,v,w},3}]/.rules
}//N

vec2 = {
    vectemp[[3]], 
    TensorProduct[vectemp[[2]], vectemp[[1]]],
TensorProduct[vectemp[[1]], vectemp[[1]], vectemp[[1]] ] }

I take the product of vec1 and vec2 and symmetrize the second component of this list of tensors and sum the result to get formula 1:
Plus[
    vec2[[1]],
    (3!/2)*Symmetrize[ vec2[[2]], Symmetric[All] ],
    vec[[3]]
]

the (3!/2) is because Symmetrize will sum all permutations and divide by the total number of them (3!). So, I multiply by 3! to cancel it, and divide by 2 because some perms are already included in the symmetric Hessian.
Here comes the problem: this method is totally redundant and ineficient. I want to do this while working with the linearly independent (LI) components of the $y_i, y_{i j}, y_{i j k}$ to generate only the LI components of $\partial_i \partial_j \partial_k f(y)$. I am pretty sure Mathematica can do that, It was already shown here how to generate only the LI components of tensor products from the LI components of the primary gradients. But I can't quite see how to do these symmetrizations while working only with the LI of the $y's$.
